# configuring spn for iis on local computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, kerberos

I want to make use of Kerberos authentication on asp.net core web application . But I want to do the custom implementation of Kerberos .I don't want to just enable the windows authentication on iis . Is it possible ? if yes how to configure spn in iis on local computer?

Comment: I like the topic, unfortuantely it's seems [overly broad](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+core+kerberos). Additionally, you'll need to expand on "custom".

Comment: custom in the sense , I want to have a method that will get the session ticket using its spn,then it will decrypt the spn and file the role of the users

Comment: So is the preference for `Kerberos` based on Windows/Domain accounts? _If not_, you can have [accounts and roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: yes based on windows account

Comment: Nothing is impossible, especially when you would like to do your own implementation. However, SPN is not something you can configure on your local machine, unless you implement your own Kerberos stack (more than just an IIS module). Like the other comment indicated, it is simply too broad to discuss, as who knows whether you have the capabilities to do a real implementation of such a complex protocol.